# How to get the difference on change?

Tags: jquery

How can I do this:

```
$('.parent').change(e => {

  var newChild = e.??? // <== this is the part I'm not sure about

  if(newChild has some class){ // pseudo-code
    array.push(newChild))
  }

})
```

*When a parent changes, get the difference.*

*If the diff is a new element, and it has a specific class, add it to the array.*

Comment: its probably e.target

Comment: if `$('.parent')` isn't a form controlwon't have a change event and not many form controls other than `<select>` have children. Provide more html details and expected behavior